# How to interrupt component from loading in its constructor?

Tags: delphi, constructor, components, delphi-2009

I would like to add to my component the conditional state when the component cannot be loaded and inform its user (developer) that this component cannot be loaded in design time and target user at runtime (safely somehow, if possible).

How can I prevent the component from loading in its constructor and how to display message (exception) from constructor safely at design time and at runtime ?

```
constructor TSomeComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  if csDesigning in ComponentState then
    if SomeIncompatibleCondition then
      begin
        // how to display message (exception) about the wrong 
        // condition and interrupt the loading of the component ?
      end;

  // is it possible to do the same at runtime ?
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: Your test is in the constructor (not and not in the Loaded method) because the message is needed before the loading of properties from the DFM begins, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raise an exception, eg:

```
constructor TSomeComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent); 
begin 
  inherited Create(AOwner); 
  if SomeIncompatibleCondition then 
    raise Exception.Create('Incompatible condition detected!');
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
Public 
   Property CreatedOK: boolean read fCreatedOK;

constructor TSomeComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  ...
  fCreatedOK := ThereIsAnIncompatibleCondition;
end;
```

Then, the programmer creates the object by:

```
MyObject := TSomeComponent.Create(Self);
if (NOT MyObject.CreatedOK) then
  ... deal with it...
```

We prefer this because it avoids lots of exception code, which can be cumbersome, and a hassle when debugging. (That's another topic though!)

Another approach we use is if the constructor has a lot of work, move the work to another method that the user *has* to call after constructing. This also has the advantage of letting us pass many values to the object easily.

```
public
  constructor Create...
  function InitAfterCreate:boolean;
end;
```

The caller does:

```
MyObject := TSomeComponent.Create
if (NOT MyObject.InitAfterCreate) then
   ... deal with it ...
```

or, if you're using InitAfterCreate to pass values, you'd define it as

```
function InitAfterCreate( Value1: Integer, etc.):boolean
```

Then InitAfterCreate can examine the state of the object and return a result.

One weakness of these approaches is that the programmer has to remember to call the InitAfterCreate or check MyObject.CreatedOk.  To protect against them failing to do so, you can put some Asserts in the beginning of some other methods of your object like:

```
procedure TForm.FormShow
begin
  Assert(fCreatedOK, "Programmer failed to check creation result.")
  ...
end;
```

In all cases, one challenge is to not terminate the Create leaving the object half-created, in an indeterminate state, which might make it hard for your destructor to know how much to destroy.